# Adding google search bar in a view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want a google search bar in my view. I have created a textfield and a search button and i tried to link it with a search method but its not working. Kindly help as i am new to iOS development field.
Thank you.

Here is "ViewController.m"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor= [UIColor cyanColor];
searchtext = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];
searchtext.delegate = self;
searchtext.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.view addSubview:searchtext];

search = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[search setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[search setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
search.frame = CGRectMake(210, 0, 100, 30);
[self.view addSubview:search];
[search addTarget:self action:@selector(gotogooglesearch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
-(void)gotogooglesearch{
NSMutableString *googleUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http//www.google.com/search?q="];
NSString * searchString = [searchtext text];

[googleUrl appendString:searchString];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrl];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this if you are planning to open the url in safari.

```
-(void)gotogooglesearch{
    NSMutableString *googleUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com/search?q="];
    NSString * searchString = [searchtext text]; //use stringbytrimmingcharacter method to strip whitespaces and newlines.

    [googleUrl appendString:searchString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrl];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

or

You can create a UIWebView outlet. Access it in your code using self.webView.

```
-(void)gotogooglesearch{
    NSMutableString *googleUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com/search?q="];
    NSString * searchString = [searchtext text]; //use stringbytrimmingcharacter method to strip whitespaces and newlines.

    [googleUrl appendString:searchString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrl];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: I think since you had missed the colon in the URL, they were not working. try the edited ans now.

Comment: my webview name is googlesearch. so when i try [self.googlesearch loadRequest:requestObj]; its throwing me an error and showing me to replace "." with "->". i tried that also but its not working.

Comment: How is the googlesearch instance declared? U might have to update the question to give us a little more understanding of the situation.

Comment: thanks for the help bro. i understood the issue and fixed it but there is 1 more problem.if i type more than 1 word in the text field with spaces in between them than its not searching and if i remove the space and make it as 1 word than its working properly. what can be the  problem.

Comment: NSString * searchString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",searchtext.text];
    NSString * searchString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",searchString1];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:searchString2];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [googlesearch loadRequest:requestObj];

Answer (score 1):

You havent added any UIWEBVIEW to show the result.
If you are using UIWEBVIEW, then

```
[self.web_view_obj loadRequest:Your_URL_STRING];
```

To OPen it in safari,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:Your_URL_STRING];
```

Comment: i have added a webview and tried but then also the search button is not working..

Comment: Try using %20, at the occurrence of Space, at the search query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the help. I actually got the answer. Just created one webview "googlesearch" and loaded the search in that.

```
-(void)gotogooglesearch{

NSString * searchString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",searchtext.text];
searchString1 = [searchString1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSString * searchString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",searchString1];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:searchString2];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[googlesearch loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)gotogooglesearch1{
    NSMutableString *googleUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com/search?q="];
    NSString * searchString = [searchtext text]; //use stringbytrimmingcharacter method to strip whitespaces and newlines.

    [googleUrl appendString:searchString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrl];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```